# Exception thrown. For more detailed information, please consult error-log-0.xml in XPage

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

I am running Xpage Application on Domino Server 8.5.3 FP1 Windows 64bit.

We are sending the bills(documents) around 2500 users. during testing ,this application works fine without any error. When we rollout the bills to user. All users are trying to open the application.

It is throwing the following error. But Application still works. At some point of time, Application gets slow and http hang. I have do restart of HTTP. Then it works fine.

I am not able to find the cause whether any error in the code or because number of users are accessing the application increases.

```
06/04/2014 10:58:53 AM  HTTP JVM: CLFAD0211E: Exception thrown. 
For more detailed information, please consult error-log-0.xml located in D:/Lotus/Domino/data/domino/workspace/logs
```

And sometimes this is also throwing ,

```
HTTP JVM: CLFAD0141E: Error processing XPage request. For more detailed information,   
please consult error-log-0.xml located in D:/IBM/Lotus/Domino/data/domino/workspace/logs
```

Please help on this query.

Comment: Please follow the advice the error message is giving and consult the files. If you do not have direct access to the server, XPages Log Reader or XPages Debug Toolbar from OpenNTF both allow you to view these files.

Comment: Basically, that console message just means "An XPages application somewhere on the server has hit some kind of error you're not handling". It tells the user to consult error-log-0.xml for a reason. Note, the number on the file increments as the server restarts (and possibly if the file gets full)

Comment: Thanks paul. I will give a try and get back with the results.

Answer (score 1):

You should start with what Paul suggests. If you haven't already downloaded and installed LogReader (by Jakob Majkilde), then you should. It is a database on your server that will read the various error file types and show them for you in an easy way. You can find it here: http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=XPages%20Log%20File%20Reader

From these log files you will then have to look at where the system complains about problems. Did you write the code in Java or Serverside Javascript (SSJS)? You have options to debug both of these  (although I cannot remember if you can debug SSJS in version 8.5.3 - it may not be available until version 9.0). But you could always add a println in the code near where you think it breaks ;-)

/John

Comment: I have written code in SSJS. And I will install LogReader too. So Next time , I can easily debug .  Today I did not have chance to get the log files. Tomorrow I will see the log and debug . Thank you very much for the time.

Answer (score 1):

> At some point of time, Application gets slow and http hang. I have do restart of HTTP. Then it works fine.

As mentioned by Paul + John, no one is going to be able to give you an exact answer from the posted message.

As you mention the application gets slows and hangs, I would also recommend watching the [XPages Masterclass](http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/xpages%20masterclass).

It is approx 4 hours of videos, and goes into detail on how to debug your application for performance issues using the [XPages Toolbox](http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/XPages%20Toolbox/releases/DAC38BA9929811B986257A1D0069FD64).

Again this isn't an exact solution. You will need to use the XPages toolbox to drill down on your code/JVM to see where it is slowing down/hanging.

Posting the stacks from the `error-log-0.xml` log file might give some hints, but with performance/hangs it's rarely that simple to find.

Comment: Simon, Thanks for the valuable tip. This happens only when many users hits the application. Now the application running properly without error too. I will install XPages Toolbox on development server and debug.

Answer (score 0):

Now Application is working without issue. I have just included exception handling in all ssjs.

Now it is not throwing error.

Thanks for all your help and time.